# nothing occured parsing JSON object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Nothing displayed while parsing JSON object including unicode data in angular js.

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.hrjournalmyanmar.com/getarticle.cfm")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.mmjobs});
});



<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in names">
            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
            </div>
        <md-divider inset></md-divider>
</md-list-item>
```

Please help me how to solve it? Because I'm very new in angularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$http.get("http://www.hrjournalmyanmar.com/getarticle.cfm")
.then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.mmjobs;});
```

> Deprecation Notice
>
> The $http legacy promise methods success and error
>   have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

To fix the json content you can write your own response transformer and fix the " quotes and transform the content to unicode.
http://plnkr.co/edit/1sZXmHZgRVUQNhOjluBU?p=preview

```
        $http.get("http://www.hrjournalmyanmar.com/getarticle.cfm", {
          'transformResponse': 
            function(data, headersGetter, status) {

              var out = '';
              angular.forEach(data, function(c) {
                var code = c.charCodeAt();
                if (code > 255) {
                  var n = Number(code).toString(16);
                  while (n.length < 4) {
                    n = '0' + n;
                  }
                  out += ('\\u' + n);
                } else {
                  out += c;
                }
              });
              out = out.replace('""', '"\\"');
              out = out.replace('" \\u', '\\" \\u');
              console.log(out);
              return angular.fromJson(out);
            }

          })
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.names = response.data;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think It is because `http://www.hrjournalmyanmar.com/getarticle.cfm` consist json data which is not parse-able(wrong).

test your json structure here:http://json.parser.online.fr/